# kivy - Buildozer: in-app billing (Google android)

Tags: api, kivy, billing, buildozer

Has any one successful used Google's in-app builling for a kivy/buildozer created app?  If so, can you give me the run down on how to install and use the APIs under a linux ubuntu system?

Comment: I did a Buildozer Android Release just so I can view the contents of the bin folder.  Looks like Buildozer includes the AIDL.java file for billing.  If everything is all there, I would just need to know how to add the billing permission to the manifest and provoke the in-app purchasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using buildozer, you add your public key to your bashrc file as:

```
           export BILLING_PUBKEY="your public key goes here in the bashrc"
```

When building the apk with buildozer, you pass the billing argument with the public key token:

```
           buildozer --with-billing $BILLING_PUBKEY android debug (or release)
```

You can then use a tool like apktool to decompile your apk, exposing the manifest.xml.  You want to add the billing permission to the manifest:

```
           <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Then use apktool to recompile the apk.  Inside your main.py you should import billing as:

```
           from android.billing import BillingService
```

Lastly, you have to sign and zipalign your apk (again if done before).

In-app billing should now be enabled for your app.  When installing the apk, you will see network communications billing as one of the app's permissions.

There is code at github which uses in-app billing but I'm not sure if that code is reliable.

Comment: I am about to attempt to implement in app purchasing. Do you have anymore information on app purchasing?

Comment: It’s not possible.  Buildozer uses the old version of Google’s in-app billing which Google no longer supports.  You have to use the newer in-app billing 3.

You can try to add all needed modules and aidl file to your root folder and import from there….just a thought (doubt if that’ll work).

Comment: You’ll find more info about in-app billing by searching on the net for “Google in-app billing 3.”

It would have been great if Kivy/Buildozer was built to handle in-app billing of today because Kivy is Python users only means to get on an hand-held device.

Comment: You can always release a free version of an app with ads and another “paid” version without ads.  That’s your only options with current Buildozer.

Comment: Thank you for you feedback. What advertising have you gotten working?

Comment: I'm not that far in my project yet, but Google has a python based api set you can download and import into your project to access other Google services.  I imagine ads can come from many sources and you'll just need internet access and the correct ad loading code in-game to show ads.  If you're on linux or running a virtual machine: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation